# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found at struct.getDescriptor().getMetaData()

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I using `oracle.sql.STRUCT` class. By following code :

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = struct.getDescriptor().getMetaData();
```

I get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 1
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:218) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:969) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1190) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3370) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3476) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4400) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initADTAttrNames(OracleTypeADT.java:2423) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.getAttributeName(OracleTypeADT.java:2246) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.StructMetaData.getColumnName(StructMetaData.java:175) ~[ojdbc14.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
```

Whay above exception occurred? What is solution?

Comment: Random guess, you have some cased column names which you haven't told Java to expect... All this really means is that Java's trying to select some metadata from the DB and that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your comment. When this happen? My code is working fine but in new envrironment  this exception occurred. What is solution?

Comment: You have two environments? The obvious next thing to do would be to check (twice) that these environments are identical in every way; especially those tables being used at the line number your exception was thrown on? Rather than just dumping a stack trace on Stack Overflow maybe it would be better if you do what _everyone_ has to do, provide a **minimal** example that demonstrates your problem. I assume this would include the DDL as well as Java in this instance.

Comment: I would also recommend reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found solution.
Problem is user that my application connect with it to database don't has grant to target type.
I added grant to the user and application worked fine.

Comment: I just had the same issue - I have also seen “Inconsistent catalog view” error if you miss a grant too!

Answer (score 3):

I found another reason for this problem. When I write objects name as lower case name oracle throw exception but when full upper case object names problem solved

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this is caused by an audit trigger which checks whether the values have a NULL value.

If the value from the SQL expression is NULL, then this error is triggered.